ESP8266 GPIO - Can a 3.3V power source connect directly to a GPIO?
if I apply 3.3V power source to a GPIO pin (pin 5 for example) on the ESP without a resistor can this damage the chip?
Mine is bricked and I think this may have been the issue. I had connected a momentary push button to the GPIO without a resistor.


What was the supply voltage?

Supply voltage is 3.3V

It sort of depends. Was it the same supply that powers the ESP, so that ESP was powered when button was pushed? Was the pin set as input or accidentally as low output? Was the button on same PCB, or was the button connected via cabling of some length? Any ESD protection from static electricity of someone operating the button? There are cases that can do damage and cases that are quite safe.

same power supply for the ESP and the push button. They are on the same PCB.
It was operating as an input and responding to the pushbutton initially. Not sure if it can change to an output whilst the program is running.

3.3V directly to the GPIO shouldn't be a problem; if it were the cause, then it's an implementation thing as @Justme is getting at. What other things do you have going on with the module?

What does the pushbutton do then, and is there a resistor as pull-down to set the low state? You can't leave an input floating and expect it to work. Your ESP might think someone is constantly pushing the button.

Ok. So I managed to flash it again and now it is working again.
I'm running custom firmware... maybe this caused it to stop working.
I'm running 100 ohm pull down resistor for the button... next built I might use a min 300 ohm just incase it gets set as an output...
